# How to display jfreechart at specified place in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jfreechart, pie-chart

I have a jsp page where i need to display the chart at specified position .But With the following codes chart is getting loaded as png image and all other css design elements  of the jsp page is not displaying....
Below is my code.

```
 DefaultPieDataset dataset = new DefaultPieDataset();

        dataset.setValue("STD", 10);
        dataset.setValue("Local", 15);
        dataset.setValue("ISD", 47);
        dataset.setValue("Inet", 20);

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D(
                "Calls by Type", // Title
                dataset, // Data
                true, // Yes, display the legend
                true, // No, don't display tooltips
                true // No, no URLs
                );
        PiePlot3D plot4 = (PiePlot3D) chart.getPlot();
        plot4.setForegroundAlpha(0.6f);
        plot4.setBackgroundPaint(Color.cyan);
        PiePlot piePlot = (PiePlot) chart.getPlot();
        StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator labelGenerator = new StandardPieSectionLabelGenerator("{0} {1} {2}");
        piePlot.setLabelGenerator(labelGenerator);
        piePlot.setLegendLabelGenerator(labelGenerator);
        response.setContentType("html");

        ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(response.getOutputStream(), chart, 400, 300);
```

Comment: what I have done is make my chart it's own servlet that returns only an image, then include that url in my jsp like I would any other image. your other option is to try using mime to include it in the same data stream.

Comment: @BevynQ Thanx for ur quick response but will u plz elaborate the first option.